# Puppet errors with cron resource

Tags: puppet

I have this in my manifest:

```
class security::sensor_apps::arkime (....) {

......
    cron {
      "file_maintenance":
        command     => "$home/db/db.pl http://secesprd01.its.auckland.ac.nz:9200 sync-files ${fqdn}
           $data/raw/",
        environment => ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", "MAILTO=r.fulton@auckland.ac.nz"],
        user        => sensors,
        weekday => 7,
        hour    => 1,
        minute  => 11;
    }
```

When `puppet agent --debug` runs I get:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Security::Sensor_apps::Arkime/Cron[file_maintenance]/ensure: created (corrective)
"-":14: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Debug: /Stage[main]/Security::Sensor_apps::Arkime/Cron[file_maintenance]: The container Class[Security::Sensor_apps::Arkime] will propagate my refresh event
```

and, unsurprisingly, the crontab entry does not get made.

I can't remember seeing error messages from puppet without the usual `Error` prefix before.

Suggestions as to what is wrong or how to diagnose the problem solicited.

Answer (score 0):

The minute line ends with a semicolon (;) instead of a comma (,) or nothing, per YAML specifications. So I'm guessing Puppet thinks your minutes are '11;' (an invalid value) instead of '11'.

Comment: but this is not a yaml file : )  Puppet resource declarations must terminate with a ;